# can't convert JSON data from MongoDB to variable usable in my code

Tags: javascript, express

Need to pull data from my MongoDB and use as variable in my web app, using expressJS & mongoose. when I request all data using the find() function I get this data as JSON with no issue. 
but now I need to be able to access the collection as use it's data as a variable in my project. please help me , I know I'm missing something.

```
router.get('/support', (req, res) => {

Message.find()
.then(messages => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        data: messages
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: 'fail',
        message: err.message
    })
})
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I didn't get your problem clearly. Can you clarify it? If you are getting JSON data correctly then what is the real problem that you are facing ?

Comment: it's not technically a problem because everything runs fine , just I don't know how to do it . what my challenge is that I want to use part of the data stored in the db collections as a variable which I can then access any where in my website .

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because  you have

```
Message.find()
```

instead of

```
Message.find({})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
router.get('/support', (req, res) => {

Message.find({}).exec()
.then(messages => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: 'success',
        data: messages
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    res.json({
        confirmation: 'fail',
        message: err.message
    })
})
});
```

First thing: add {} as a query criterion. Maybe mongoose will accept empty argument but I'm not sure how it handles this (I don't see any mention in docs about such a syntax).

Second: `findOne` does not return a promise. Query result has a convenience `then` method but I'm not sure about `catch`. You should execute `exec()` to get a js promise.

[Queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)

Comment: Thanks this made my data into an array properly , but say I have this object in my db 
      {"_id":"5ca26b5f4a7f57160c3ee2b4","sender":"getmoney","subject":"fake4","body":"lets try this random text strings to create and populate our array for tests                        ","__v":0}

And I want to use the sender as a variable, how can I use it in my code ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with sender? Inside "then" `messages` is an array of objects, so you can access a `sender` field from the first message received by `messages[0].sender`. You can also get a list of all senders `messages.map(m => m.sender)`. 
You can assign a result of any of those expression to a variable and use it in whatever way you want.

Comment: I'm creating a messaging platform to understand expressJS more, so I want to be able to show these messages on the support route. but for each message I want the sender to display right beside it . that's why I need to use the sender & body data from the collection as variables so I can design my ejs file (template engine of choice) using these variables to display the messages and sender to each user of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Marcin's comment would work just fine, or if you don't need all the propreties in your view you could send only this:

```
 res.json({
    confirmation: 'success',
    message: messages.body,
    sender: messages.sender
 })
```

Comment: yes I see it now , but I used the whole collection {messages} rather than this method and it also worked . if you can see below my update to the question I think I did it correctly .

Answer (score 0):

After receiving some pointers from kind users here, I managed to get it to work. I don't know if its the right way to do it but my code works how I want so I decided to update with what worked for me. I update the middleware to this

```
router.get('/support', (req, res) => {
    Message.find({})
    .then(messages => {
        res.render("support", {messages}); // I rendered the template 
})
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({
            confirmation: 'fail',
            message: err.message
        })
    })   
});
```

and then in my EJS file I simply added It

```
<p><%= messages[0].sender %></p>
```

This worked for me